# Dynamic show the Delete Button in listview on select option

Tags: android, android-listview

I have designed an list view which has one imageview, textview, and button. initially the imageview and textview will be visible on clicking the imageview delete button will visible for selected view but my problem is while selecting the next list option i need to hide the button i need to show only one button at a time. can anyone help me please?

```
public class HistoryMenu extends MainActivity {

public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";  
public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";

public static Boolean deletedispflag=false;
public static View selectdelete=null;
String optionSelectedValue;
ArrayList<String> listString;
ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
ListView settingsSubList;
LayoutInflater linf;
//  public String[] stringList={"N @ 17.3 MPH (16-18)","10:25, 20 June 2013","N @ 17.3 MPH (16-18)","10:25, 20 June 2013","N @ 17.3 MPH (16-18)","10:25, 20 June 2013","N @ 17.3 MPH (16-18)","10:25, 20 June 2013"};
//  HistoryListAdapters historyListAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history_menu);
    settingsSubList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settings_sub_list);

    LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.centered_menu_title, null);

    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v,layout);

    listString=new ArrayList<String>();
    listString.add("history object 1");
    listString.add("history object 2");
    listString.add("history object 3");
    listString.add("history object 4");
    listString.add("history object 5");


    MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.history_option_selector, listString);

    settingsSubList.setAdapter(adapter);
    settingsSubList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

        }
    });

}



   public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {       

       int previousDegrees = 0;
       int degrees = 90;
       RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); //, 200, 200); // canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);    

       Context context;
       int layoutResourceId;
       ArrayList<String> historyitems = new ArrayList<String>();


       public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<String> historyitems) 
       {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, historyitems);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.historyitems = historyitems;
       }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {
           animation.setDuration(1000L);


            View item = convertView;            
            if (item == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    item = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            } 



            TextView items = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.history_list_option_text);
            final ImageView select_option = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.history_list_option_select_image);
            final Button delete = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.history_list_option_delete_button);
            delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);               
            String itemtext = historyitems.get(position);               
            items.setText(itemtext);

            select_option.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                      select_option.startAnimation(animation);
                      if(deletedispflag == false)
                      {
                          delete.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);                        
                          selectdelete = v;
                          deletedispflag=true;
                      }
                      else if(deletedispflag==true)
                      {                   

                          delete.setVisibility(selectdelete.INVISIBLE);

                          deletedispflag=false;
                      }

                      Toast.makeText(context, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
            });


            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Toast.makeText(context, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


       return item;
     }



   }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);           
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);            
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.activity_in_left_to_right_animation,R.drawable.activity_out_right_to_left_animation);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by storing the reference previously clicked button

```
private Button prevDelete;
```

And change click listener to something like below:

```
select_option.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(prevDelete!=null){
        prevDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }

     delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     prevDelete = delete;
     select_option.startAnimation(animation);
     selectdelete = v;

     Toast.makeText(context, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```